# Best practice for passing parameters in python

Tags: python

I have made a class in python than has some functions. One of the functions returns the result. This function internally uses other functions. I have a lot of parameters, which have to be accessible to all the functions of the class. Initialising the class with these parameters in the constructor, will not be ok, because in that case, I have to make an object every time, I want to specify new parameters. Although I can pass these parameters to each and every function, it looks very redundant. I know we can send parameters using args and kwargs. I wanted to ask if there is any neat(by this I mean not writing redundant code) way of solving this problem. 
Thank you very much for helping.

Some code

```
class BoundingText:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def check(self, scale, text,
              font, pad_top, pad_bottom,
              box_width, box_height, offset, p=1):
        pass

    def get_image(self, x, y, w, h, img, text, offset, pad_percent,
                  align="left", font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                  line_width=3, color=(255, 0, 0)):
        pass

# more functions using all these parameters.
```

Comment: Yes there is, you stated it - use `**kwargs`, but in my opinion, *explicit is better than implicit*

Comment: Do `check` and `get_image` use `self` at all? If not, why are they methods rather than regular functions? The point of making `BoundingText` a class would be to reuse values across multiple method calls. If that's never needed, the need for `BoundingText` at all comes into question.

Comment: There's nothing wrong, per se, with having lots of parameters if the function really needs them. However, you might group *related* parameters into an additional class (or even just a `dict`).

Comment: It's hard to suggest a cleaner interface without knowing more about how an instance of `BoundingText` is used.

Comment: @chepner I understand but suppose I wanted this functionality to be accessible to the user as a module. How can I achieve that without using a class?

Comment: @Tomerikoo Blindly using `**kwargs` to avoid explicitly naming parameters is more of a hack than an example of good interface design.

Comment: @satindersingh Modules can define top-level functions. This isn't Java.

Comment: @chepner I agree. I meant that if OP is simply bothered with the lengthiness of the arguments list, that's an option. Personally I would prefer an explicit, long arguments list

Comment: To revisit the question of grouping, `get_image` appears to take two different kinds of arguments: some that describe the shape and position of the image, and some that describe the formatting of the image independent of its shape or position.